# troubleshoot wrong file permissions

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries, file-permissions

I have a process that creates a log file, with file permissions 644. However, when I run the process loading a specific shared object library using LD_PRELOAD, the file permissions are set to 2101(specifically the setgid permission is set). I do not have the source code for the program that creates the process, but I do have the source code for the .so file. I know for sure that the file permissions are a result of the .so file being loaded, because when I load the .so file for a program(that I wrote) that creates a file, the file permissions have the setuid/setgid bit set. I tried using gdb for the program I wrote but I am not able to step through the code. I just get a segmentation fault error the moment I start the program with the .so file loaded using gdb. How should I troubleshoot this problem? I don't see any file permissions being set in the source code of the .so file. The program I wrote is very simple, it looks something like this -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf(" This is my program");
    system("touch /tmp/myfile.txt");

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't see any file permissions being set in the source code of the .so file.

Does your `.so` interpose `open`?

One way to create files with "random" permissions is to (incorrectly) interpose `open` like so:

```
int open(const char *fname, int flags)
{
    ... do whatever
    return real_open(fname, flags);  // problem: omits 3rd argument to open
                                     // and passes "garbage" permissions when
                                     // O_CREATE is in flags.
}
```

> I just get a segmentation fault error the moment I start the program with the .so file loaded using gdb.

When GDB runs your program, it invokes `$SHELL` (to take care of any input/output redirection). Your shell likely doesn't like having its `open` interposed incorrectly either.

Comment: Just one more clarification, the right way to do the interpose would be to write a wrapper function?

Comment: @user4002112 I am not sure what you are asking. IF you write an interposer, you need to write it *correctly*. In case of `open`, it needs 3 arguments, not 2.

Comment: You were right, I haven't written an interposer before, but I found the solution, all I needed was to put an additional argument for the permissions in the defintion of the handler.